# Importrange and dropdown box

Tags: xcode, import, google-sheets-formula, dropdown

I have 4 separate spreadsheets
SpreadSheets1 - Student 1,
spreadsheets

- Student 2,
  spreadsheets
- Student 3,
  spreadsheets
- Master.
  In the master sheet, I have a Dropdown list with Student1, Student 2, Student 3,in C2
  when I select student 1 in drop-down box C2, data in D2 & F2 of master should go to spreadsheets 1 - Student 1 F & G Column, please help
  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1J-W7p9SmK8pamApYmxlOWbnM6XmmyB4m?usp=sharing
  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=FILTER({IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-MMV9GrJi0yj23xyYB84Fqt4LwxzegH8qDkLmg2tlbE/edit","Sheet1!D:D"),IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-MMV9GrJi0yj23xyYB84Fqt4LwxzegH8qDkLmg2tlbE/edit","Sheet1!F:F")},IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-MMV9GrJi0yj23xyYB84Fqt4LwxzegH8qDkLmg2tlbE/edit","Sheet1!C:C")="Student 1")
```

Comment: Hi bro can you elaborate

Comment: Added, please check.

Comment: Still not able to attached the link of the sheets https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1J-W7p9SmK8pamApYmxlOWbnM6XmmyB4m?usp=sharing

Comment: Oh, they are different spreadsheets but not different sheets.

Comment: It is working. But I doubt you are not asking correctly what you expect.

Comment: yes bro you are correct my mistake only if you can recheck my question

Comment: Updated. Please check if you have any question.

Comment: Good Work you are awesome